# How to cook a Major Health Potion?

Tags: candy-box

The book only gives limited information.

For how many seconds do I have to mix the first 100 candies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You follow the directs exactly as written. Throw in 100 lollipops, press the Mix button, then throw in 100 candies while it's mixing. Press the stop button when the mix counter reaches 20. Press the bottle button.

Comment: For some reason I was reading 100 candies, instead of lollipops.. guess it's time to stop playing

Comment: My mistake was that i tried to wait 20 seconds after putting the candies, not the mixing start

Answer (score 1):

You can also use multiples of 100 to create multiple potions in the same way you create multiple minor health potions.

For example: Throw in 500 lolipops, start mixing, throw in 500 candies, stop at 20 seconds, put it into bottles, and you'll get 5 major health potions.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work using user48017's instructions, but I did eventually get it to work.   I'm not sure what parts are important, but here are my steps:

1.) 100 lollipops, toss them in.
2.) type 100 candies into box
3.) Mix, then quickly press the 'put all things in the cauldron
4.) wait till timer passes 20, 21 or so is fine and stop.

should be good!